# Boot into Ubuntu from Android Tablet with Live USB Drive

Tags: 12.04, boot, live-usb, android

I have an Android ASUS Slider tablet. I have successfully installed UBUNTU to an 8GB thumb drive. I would like to boot into the thumb drive the same way I do with a windows system except I would like to do this with my Android tablet. I only know how to boot into recovery mode with the tablet, but when I plug the USB drive into the tablet I do not see the option to boot into my tablet.

What is the best route to take.

thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all things understand this. The Android tablets use ARM processors, SoC as they are called. Your regular Desktop Ubuntu is for x86 CPU's, so of course you don't see anything moreover, Does your Android tablet support dual boot?, Does your ROM support it?, Do you have a kernel that supports it?, etc. Not that if it does it will boot Ubuntu at all, you need the ARM Ubuntu image if at anything, and that doesn't mean you will get to boot it. I'd suggest you go to XDA-developers.

Comment: Thank you for this information, I do not know if this is possible, but I will research the information you have requested and follow-up promptly.

Comment: @uri your comment should be an answer without leaving the question unanswered. I strongly suggest you to add an answer

Comment: @UriHerrera - Some Android tablets use Intel chips, which are in fact x86 CPU. Now getting a functioning BIOS is a whole different matter...

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. As Uri Herrera mentioned in the comments, since Ubuntu is not an ARM-based operating system, it cannot be run on ARM-based Android tablets like yours. You may have luck with finding an unofficial build of Ubuntu Mobile on the list. Although it may be possible if your tablet is x86-based but that is not common.

Answer (score 0):

look at this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0PNsnNe3E0

It isn't dual booting,and runs on top of Android And might be slower to run two oses but this is the quick and easy way to do it.

Comment: Could you add a bit more information? As it stands it is almost a link-only answer and that link might become invalid at any time.

Answer (score 0):

I have an Acer A500 tablet, and I'm happy with it. I suggest you use libsdl but it is still an emulator, the other possibility is to use a patch so that when you boot you have the ability to boot the tablet in APX mode.

Comment: Por favor, cuando uses AskUbuntu, usa ingles en todo momento. Tambien, no uses la sección para respuestas para hacer comentarios. Usala solo para responder la pregunta.